# enqueue is not working (i have external file in coustom plugin in folder assets/js/loginpluginscript.js)

Tags: wordpress

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

    wp_register_script('loginscript', plugins_url('/assets/js/loginpluginscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false);


    wp_enqueue_script('loginscript');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Comment: where you put your code?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this for enqueue scripts:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_script('loginscript', plugins_url('/assets/js/loginpluginscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```